# Jest encountered an unexpected token - While running snapshot update for package import

Tags: jestjs

({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './JsonDiffComponent';

When I am trying to run the jest snapshot update for one of the dependent component with the json-diff-react package imported in it. I am getting above error . Any leads on this is helpful.

Solutions provided by Jest  -

```
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
```

Tried them but none of them is working